# Compare two columns (A&B), If they match, output C to D

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Working on a database in excel that i have been having issues with.
I want to match Column A and B, if they match, write Column C to Column D.

Example Dataset

Sheet 1 (Client Database)

```
Name, ClientID,Rate Type, Hourly Rate, ect
```

Sheet 2

```
Name, Client ID, Rate Type, Hours Worked, Hourly Rate, Total Billed
```

I want to be able to put in the Client Name, and the Rate Type, and have that pull out the Hourly Rate.
Client Name can be duplicated because of Rate Type, 
Client ID is the same for every client name so i cant match on that and use vlookup.

Comment: Update: I have a working formula, but i need it to work on different sheets.

=INDEX(B4:D1159,MATCH(1,(B4:B1159=A2)*(C4:C1159=B2),0),3)

Aray is on a different Sheet.

Comment: Hi James, it's a bit easier when you include some sample data and detail exactly what output you expect. We might be able to suggest a better method. If you want to refer to `A1` on a different sheet just replace it with `Sheet2!A1`, for example

Comment: Wouldn't the "Client ID" be unique?